# Beginner question on how to connect a microphone to my TV's external speakers

Tags: microphone, preamp

I have a new set of karaoke microphones that I need to connect to my speakers. I have heard that I would either need a pre-amp or a mixer to connect the microphone to my speakers. I'm not quite sure which one I should get. I know that the mixer mixes my microphone's audio with my TV's audio output, which then can be outputted through my speakers. And that a pre-amp just amplifies the audio signal. Which one should I be getting? And does the quality of the product matter?

There are some $30 mixers on amazon, but I have no idea if they are good enough for karaoke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$30 mixers are typically plenty good for karaoke, and should work well for your purpose.

A pre-amp for microphones would give you a line-level output from the mics, which is close to that you'll find on the audio inputs of your home theater receiver, or whatever you are using to power your speakers.  These pre-amps are built into mixers.